# Problem with calculating time complexity for given piece of code

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am having trouble with calculating time complexity for this code.

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        count ++;
```

I know that outer loop will be execute `n` times, but I can't figure out how many times will inner loop execute.
Can someone show me the answer and how this can be figure out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop executes `i` times. The value of `i` will be 0, then 1, then 2, then 3... up to `n - 1` on the last iteration of the outer loop.

So the total number of iterations of the inner loop will be 1 + 2 + ... + (n-1) = n(n - 1)/2, which is O(n²).

A more informal way of deriving this is to say that on average, `i` is about n/2, so the inner loop iterates O(n) times (but not exactly n times). So the total number of iterations is n (from the outer loop) multiplied by O(n), giving O(n²).

Comment: Where did you get division by 2? I don't get where it came from.

Comment: The formula n(n-1)/2 is just a standard formula for the sum of numbers from 1 to n-1. The statement that `i` is on average about n/2 is just giving approximately the midpoint between its lowest value (0) and its highest value (n-1) since it varies linearly between them.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a little sketch on paper. The outer loop is the rows the number of columns  are the number of  `count++` operations in the inner loop.
The result will be a triangle. That is n² / 2 which is O(n²)

Example n=5:

```
i=0:   
i=1:   x
i=2:   xx
i=3:   xxx
i=4:   xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: O of n square]

(We can ignore the execution time of the loops' condition checking and counter increment)